# can I open the same pouchDB on different functions

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I'm working with angularJS and want to manage the creation and update of database and docs with functions inside a service but I'm not sure if I should send the database as a parameter, like:

```
var myDatabase = new PouchDB('appData', { skip_setup: true, auto_compaction: true});
myService.addSomething(myDatabase);
myService.getSomething(myDatabase);
```

or should/can I open the connection on every function without problems like:

```
myService.addSomething = function(){
var myDatabase = new PouchDB('appData', { skip_setup: true, auto_compaction: true});
/* add something code*/
};

myService.getSomething = function(){
var myDatabase = new PouchDB('appData', { skip_setup: true, auto_compaction: true});
/* get something code*/
};
```

since I can't find any official documentation on how to (or if I should) close the database, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For working with the same database, a single `new PouchDB()` is sufficient

Comment: Ahhh, as a general variable on the service and just fetch the data when needed from it. It is so obvious now.